# How can I make schema to connect to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const db = mongoose.connection;
require("./db/config");
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{type: String, required:true},
    email:{type :String, required:true },
    password:{type :String, required:true}
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);

const static_path= path.join(__dirname, "/public");
app.use(express.static(static_path)); 

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.post("/registration", (req,res)=> {
    const data = {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password 
    }
    db.collection('users').insertOne(data,(err, collection)=>{
        if(err){throw err;}
        console.log("Succesful");
    });
    return res.redirect("home-page.html")
})


app.listen(port),()=> {console.log(`on port 3000`)};
```

Terminal showing "E11000 duplicate key error collection" when registering with the same email.
How can I register with the same email again? Want to make schema to connect with nodejs.

Comment: You may have a unique index for field `email`.  If you don't want a unique index on `email`, you could drop the index or modify the index so that `email` field values need not be unique.

Comment: Try to change the email property in `userSchema` to `email:{type :String, required:true, unique:false }` and try again.

Comment: Changed it to 'unique:false' but still showing the same error.

Comment: What are the current indexes on the `users` collection?